# How to split a dataframe in sub groups of 5 rows?

Tags: r, split, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
xtsdata <- structure(c(0.44696179, 0.395227931, 0.477439822, 0.295309508, 
  0.712614891, 0.689317114, 0.599395023, 0.610971864, 0.337625508, 0.529290134,
  0.596002106, 0.412324483, 0.244831259, 0.443123542, 0.484748065, 0.686165972,
  0.711764909, 0.604578061, 0.42144923, 0.669898641, 0.735845192, 0.592157589,
  0.81714156, 0.380346873, 0.684386001, 0.672967504, 0.508142689, 0.244274776,
  0.548213564, 0.417804342, 0.612475603, 0.665148957, 0.756447435, 0.582448567,
  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.71708817, 0.528262036, 0.597354154, 0.886971243, 0.624771744,
  0.498557661, 0.382554107, 0.464373083, 0.425888914, 0.747806533, 0.788271626,
  0.407617084, 0.784747938, 0.466987506, 0.554976586, 0.621751352, 0.501173993,
  0.323827823, 0.659625721, 0.502665703, 0.626577183, 0.458883576, 0.572507952,
  0.388946538, 0.897384403, 0.784054708, 0.652210478, 0.850226608, 0.514172118,
  0.780114865, 0.710307692, 0.714749488, 0.248817293, 0.576462902, 0.690210031),
  class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC",
  tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1288828800, 1288915200, 1289174400, 1289260800,
  1289347200, 1289433600, 1289520000, 1289779200, 1289865600, 1289952000,
  1290038400, 1290124800, 1290384000, 1290470400, 1290556800), tzone = "UTC",
  tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(15L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Stock1", "Stock10",
  "Stock100", "Stock101", "Stock102")))
```

How can I split this into a list which has 3 data frames containing 5 rows each? I also need the code to be independent of the number of rows of the data.

Comment: The basic approach is to use something like `split(xtsdata, rep(1:3, each = 5))`. What part do you want to be independent of the data? The number of resulting splits? Or the number of rows in each split?

Comment: my data extends beyond 15 rows. could i use nrows(xtsdata)/5 instead of 3?

Comment: i would like R to determine the amount of resulting splits on its own. but still use a predetermined output size (5 in this case)

Comment: That should work, and you can also look into using the `%/%` operator.

Comment: i've never used %% could you provide me with an example or put it as a solution to my question and i will approve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a helper function like the following:

```
groupMaker <- function(x, y) 0:(x-1) %/% y
```

Then, you can `split` the object with:

```
split(xtsdata, groupMaker(nrow(xtsdata), 5))
```

---

The `groupMaker` function here basically lets you conveniently create groups even if they may not be divisible without remainders:

```
groupMaker(15, 5)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
groupMaker(13, 5)
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2
```

---

Other possible ways to define `groupMaker` would be to use `rep` or `gl`, like this:

```
groupMaker_2 <- function(x, y) gl(ceiling(x/y), y)[seq_len(x)]
groupMaker_3 <- function(x, y) rep(1:ceiling(x/y), each = y, length.out = x)
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to determine which is the most efficient (and I doubt there would be any major differences in performance in general).

Comment: thank you very much it works perfectly on my full data. could you please provide a description of what groupMaker does?

Comment: @AlexBădoi, the `%/%` operator is for integer division. So, for example, `3 %/% 5 = 0` and `6 %/% 5 = 1`. We can use basic vectorization using `:` to use this operator to create our groups. However, it needs to be modified by shifting the input vector to start at "0" instead of 1.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Instead of `groupMaker` you could use `gl()` or `rep(each=)` from base.

Comment: @NealFultz, is there a direct way to deal with groups that don't divide without remainder (as I've done with `groupMaker(13, 5)`? With `rep`, all that I can think of is a combination of `ceiling` and adding the `length.out` argument, and I'm not sure how you would handle that in `gl`. (I came up with `gl(ceiling(13/5), 5)[seq_len(13)]` but I'm not sure if there's a better approach.)

Comment: Does he mean `gl(15, 5, 15)` and `gl(15, 5, 13)`?  Wrapped in `droplevels()` too, possibly

Comment: Or actually, `gl(ceiling(13/5), 5, 13)` would do it.

Comment: @RichardScriven, nice options. Thanks.